# Hover areas activated in wrong location with content aligned to center

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover, opacity

when i change the alignment of page from left to center, the image map hyperlinks still work at the correct location over image, but the hover areas (to change opacity) are triggering too far to the left of where they should.

is there a way to add the opacity change to the image map itself, since that seems to function correctly regardless of alignment?

also, i noticed the hyperlinks are unclickable if underneath the area blocks. ideally, i'd like to have the links and hover opacity function simultaneously upon mouseover.

here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<a id="area1" class="area"></a>
<a id="area2" class="area"></a>
<a id="area3" class="area"></a>
<img src="logoandmenu.jpg" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
<!-- #$-:Image map file created by GIMP Image Map plug-in -->
<!-- #$-:GIMP Image Map plug-in by Maurits Rijk -->
<!-- #$-:Please do not edit lines starting with "#$" -->
<!-- #$VERSION:2.3 -->
<!-- #$AUTHOR:Vampita -->
<area shape="rect" coords="474,0,643,72" href="about_us.html" />
<area shape="rect" coords="644,0,813,72" href="fore_sale.html" />
<area shape="rect" coords="814,0,984,72" href="sold.html" />
</map>
<img src="background2.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here's my css:

```
body {
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#content {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background: black;
    width:100%
    text-align:left;
}

.area {
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    height:72px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:170;
}
#area1 {
    left:474px;
}
#area2 {
    left:644px;
}
#area3 {
    left:814px;
}
#area1:hover, #area2:hover, #area3:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so it took a couple hours of research b/c i'm a noob, but i got an idea from a youtube video which explained positioning very well (https://youtu.be/GqCj_sHxzGE). apparently aligning objects relative to the center of the page is more complicated than i thought.

i ended up giving up on image map, and just using the area blocks with hover functionality in css (see code below).

```
.area {
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:170px;
    height:72px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-18px;
}

#area2 {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:152px;
}

#area3 {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:322px;
}

#area1:hover, #area2:hover, #area3:hover:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```